# Trouble storing uploaded file into MySql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, referential-integrity

Hi I'm currently developing a quick prototype for my degree project. I have a previous form where users will select some options from dynamic dropdowns and when these have been saved into the tables the next page is for a user to upload a file. This file is then stored into a separate table with a foreign key referencing one other table. The problem is with the file upload page, I haven't included the the variable that represents the foreign key as i wanted to see if i could get it to work first. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

The error i receive is either for the the name of the upload file not being a valid column name in the fields of the insert query or

If I try to change the sql i get insert or update can not be done on a child table as the referential integrity is breached.

Am I being thick? Ive been stuck for a few hours now.

heres the php

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'upload')
{

$uploadfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$uploadname = $_FILES['upload']['name'];

if(is_uploaded_file($uploadname)) {


$uploadtype = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
$uploaddata = file_get_contents($uploadfile);



// Prepare user-submitted values for safe database insert

$uploadname = mysql_real_escape_string($uploadname);
$uploadtype = mysql_real_escape_string($uploadtype);
$uploaddata = mysql_real_escape_string($uploaddata);

$sql = "INSERT INTO product_logs (fileName, mimeType, fileData)
        VALUES (".$uploadname.",".$uploadtype.",".$uploaddata.")";
$exesql=mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
}
else {
echo 'Error: File could not be uploaded.';
}   
}
include("file.html.php");
```

and here is the file.html.php

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label for="upload">Upload File:
            <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"/></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the structure of the product_logs table

```
Field       Type           Null Key       Default         Extra
logID       int(5)         NO   PRI         NULL           auto_increment
dateCreated date           NO               NULL    
malResultID int(6)         NO   MUL         NULL    
mimeType    varchar(50)    NO               NULL    
fileData    mediumblob     NO               NULL    
fileName    varchar(255)   NO               NULL
```

Comment: Thanks everyone I managed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your Sql like-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product_logs (fileName, mimeType, fileData)
        VALUES ('".$uploadname."','".$uploadtype."','".$uploaddata."')";
```

Also as we have seen your table name is product_logs

can you share the structure of the product_logs table? so that we have a better clarification of your question.

Thanks

Comment: Field Type Null Key Default Extra
    logID int(5) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
    dateCreated date NO  NULL 
    malResultID int(6) NO MUL NULL 
    mimeType varchar(50) NO  NULL 
    fileData mediumblob NO  NULL 
    fileName varchar(255) NO  NULL

Comment: So you have to enter dateCreated, malResultID also in your sql statement as these fields are  also not null. Another Question - is malResultID is referred as foreign key from any other table?

Comment: Sorry I re-edited my original post with the structure Im a bit of a newbbie so if I put them to null this will allow me to just try the upload to see if it works? Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Yes, if you put dateCreated, malResultID as null, the above statement should work. Hope this will sove your problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks my friend that helped a lot I cant believe I was doing something so stupid. Many thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you forgot single quote here

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product_logs (fileName, mimeType, fileData)
VALUES ('".$uploadname."','".$uploadtype."','".$uploaddata."')";
```

and stop using `mysql_*` its deprecated, use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quotes around your values in the query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product_logs (fileName, mimeType, fileData)
        VALUES ('".$uploadname."','".$uploadtype."','".$uploaddata."')";
                ^--             ^ ^               ^ ^               ^
```

please note that storing files in a DB is rarely a good idea, and leads to major problems down the road.

If you're allowing large uploads, please note that you're wasting large amounts of memory holding TWO copies of the uploaded file in memory. A slightly LESS bad method would be

```
$sql = "INSERT .... " . mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents(...));
```

saving you at least one copy of the file's worth of space.